# In PySpark RDD, how to use foreachPartition() to print out the first record of each partition?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

In PySpark RDD, how to use `foreachPartition()` to print out the first record of each partition?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
def f(iterator):
   print(iterator.next())
```

or

```
def f(iterator):
   print(list(iterator)[0])
```

Then, you can apply one of the above functions to an RDD as follows:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
rdd1.foreachPartition(f)
```

Note that this will print in each of spark workers so you should access the workers' logs to see the results.

For more information check the documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=foreach#pyspark.RDD.foreachPartition)